# uninstall msi package through system service failed: Source is invalid due to client source out of sync (product code is the same)

Tags: service, installation, wix

I use WiX 3.7 to write an installer, and I will install a c# system service will try to reinstall the software, using msiexec -x {product_code} -quiet.  My OS is Win8
   I first install the software through UI, and after a while, the service will create a new process and start to call msiexec, but it failed.
   Could you help me on this? I have been struggling for a long time!
   Thanks very much!

I have logs as follows:

```
MSI (s) (7C:80) [00:22:01:708]: Warning: The package code in the cached package 'C:\windows\Installer\134f7d5.msi' does not match the registered package code.  Cached       
MSI (s) (7C:80) [00:22:01:724]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to client source out of sync (product code is the same).
```

Answer (score 1):

What account is the service and thus the new process running under?  Default accounts (e.g. LocalSystem) might not have rights to access the msi information.

Comment: I use <ServiceInstall> element in WiX to install a new system, from the result of services.msc, I can see the service is run under local system account
  The system account should have the highest privilege so I expect it could uninstall the software, but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

That message means that a package is installed with the same `ProductCode` (set via the `Product/@Id` attribute) but is not the same package. This usually happens if you install a package, rebuild it (so the new package gets a new "package code") then try to uninstall with the rebuilt package. It can also happen if something is causing source resolution during uninstall and the Windows Installer finds the newly rebuilt package in the place where it expects the old package.

To get unstuck, try re-cache/reinstalling with the newer package then uninstalling:

```
msiexec /fv path\to\your.msi /l*v install.txt /qb
msiexec /x path\to\your.msi /l*v uninstall.txt /qb
```

After that, test your scenarios again without changing the MSI in between the updates. You'll slowly be able to track down what is changing in your system that is getting the Windows Installer confused and unhappy.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you suggest, but actually, I didn't build a newer package, my service is just to call msiexec.exe to uninstall my software through specifying the product code, from part of the log, I can see the system do find the msi file , but it think the cached msi is a newer one, blocking the uninstallation